# SSD upgraded: Windows boot up on 8 seconds, but BIOS need more than 15 seconds. What should I do?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Motivated by boot-up time decrease, yesterday I upgraded my hard disk to a SSD.

Everything goes ok, Windows Seven now is booting up in less than 10 seconds(from more than 40 before upgrade) but my BIOS Post by itselfs spends more than 15 seconds(I'm suposing that BIOS time starts when I turn computer on until the first Windows splash screen).I mean, my BIOS time didn't benefited from disk upgrade. I already tried to check for new BIOS versions and for configuration alternatives but not sucessful.

There is something that I could try to reduce BIOS boot time beyond these two options or even buying a new motherboard?

Comment: You were doing far better than average before your SSD upgrade.  Count your blessings.

Comment: Why on earth would your SSD increase your BIOS boot times?

Comment: It did not increased, bios was already 15s before ssd but i didnt realised... free fell to edit my post and clarify speaching...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be an option to skip some checks.

Some BIOSes have options like "fast boot" or similar which will skip memory checking and save few seconds of boot time.

Another point would be to see which video card is set as default. I've seen many BIOSes which are set to by default try to boot a PCI video card, but the system's main video card is PCI-E. That could save few seconds too.

Another thing would be network boot ROMs which can take few seconds top load and would not be needed since the computer boots form local drive.

Yet another thing to add to the disable list would be RAID support, if it's not needed and support for extra disk controllers. Many motherboards have additional drive controllers which may not need to be used if there are few drives. It may be needed to physically reconnect drives to the ports provided by the controller on the chipset. After that, the controller can be disabled and that may save some boot time.

One more thing that might make an impact would be to disable floppy drive in BIOS, if the computer doesn't have one. Some newer motherboards may not even have floppy support anymore, but a significant number of those I've seen which do, have floppy set to standard 1.44 floppy in BIOS and are set not to show errors if there isn't one connected. That might save some time during boot.

Sometimes SATA and PATA drives may need some time to initialize and that time can depend on the port the drive is connected to. So it may be smart idea to disconnect all drives and see how much time it takes for BIOS to show that it can't find any bootable devices. If there is a significant difference, then it may be a good idea to try experimenting with connecting drives to different ports on the motherboard (but make sure only ports provided by the integrated drive controller are used!). I've seen cases where a HDD could take as much as 30 seconds to "initialize" on one port and only take a couple on another.

Comment: I would highly recommend, not to use these fast-boot options. BIOS checks are there for a reason, instead of such things I would use standby or hibernation mode from your OS. +1 for the rest.

Comment: Setting the HD as the first boot device can also help as the BIOS will not have to check for other bootable media before loading windows.

Comment: @bamboon They are there because of tradition and not because of any specific reason for them to be there. BIOS memory check won't actually detect any major memory errors and there's no absolutely  point of running it at ever boot in a non-critical system. Even so, the fast-boot options don't disable the checks, instead the checks are run at every n boots, where n depends on BIOS settings which are often not visible to user. .

Answer (score 5):

Well, the BIOS has to initialze every component of your rig, so one thing you can do is to turn stuff off you don't need, like interface ports you don't need.
In addition to that you can set from which media the BIOS should boot first, and disable the others, this could give some boost, too.

All in all you can't speed up the BIOS boot that much, however you gonna spend the most time of your computer usage in windows, where you will also profit very much from your SSD, so just relax and enjoy your SSD.

Comment: Seconded. What's the matter with a 50% decrease in boot time, unless your user experience specifically benefits from a quick boot time (i.e., in a netbook or other highly portable, often booting machine)?

Comment: For a often booting machine, there is the standy-by feature of windows ->boot time of ~2 secs